# Google Sheet OAuth scopes to only access a few files?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

We have a restricted app in which we control user accounts creation. We also use Google Sign-in. Currently the app is unverified and its fine since all users are in our GSuite domain. But we want to expand it to user outside our GSuite domain.

The user can provide in our apps a link to a spreadsheet, and the app will modify the sheet on user request.

Is there a way to only request a `OAuth` scope that gives access to a specific file only ?  The 
 `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` seems overkill for our usage.

Note: The spreadsheets already exists, so the permission `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` would not work in our case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use a `service account` instead of an `app`:

- The `service account` will have a generated e-mail. The documents can be shared with that e-mail.
- You can download the access credentials to the service account in a JSON file. So in sense of access they are pretty much like an app, just they don't need to go through a verification process.
- Using those credentials you'll have access to only the files that were shared with the service account through its e-mail address.

This is a nice example project that shows the steps required in the UI with screenshots:

- https://github.com/juampynr/google-spreadsheet-reader

Comment: This is such a fantastic way of doing things!

Comment: Can't figure up how to convert these credentials into the oauth token, i.e. the sample oauth script does not work on this, says: "Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present."

Comment: @Nakilon You don't need an OAUTH token with the service account. The user only needs to share his file with the e-mail of the service account.

Comment: And how then I use these credentials to consume Sheets API? What flow?

Answer (score 6):

There is no such scope.

You can see in the official Sheets API docs that, for API calls that will modify the spreadsheet, the only allowed scopes are these ones (see [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate#authorization-scopes), [append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#authorization-scopes), or [clear](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear#authorization-scopes), for example):

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

Considering that `drive.file` is not an option, and that `drive` is even more "overkill" than `spreadsheets`, there is currently no scope that fits your needs.

#### Feature Request:

This could change in the future, though. There is currently an open Feature Request in Issue Tracker about restricting the access of apps to just specific folders:

- [Issue #36760598: Drive Restrict access to folder when authorizing applications](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760598)

You can click the star on the top left of the referenced page in order to keep track of this.

Comment: Quick follow up, after much digging and testing, we found out that `drive.install` and `Drive UI Integration` allow the user to `Open` a file with our app, and this gives only access to the opened files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `drive.file` scope for existing files, but you have to use it with the `Google Picker API` that shows a promot for end users to select the specific files / sheets that they want to share with your app.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth#benefits