# Google Drive API: Edit shared files using a less scary scope

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to edit Google Drive files created with my nodeJs webapp and owned by me or shared with me.

Using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive/file" scope I can edit files owned by me.

To edit also files shared with me I must use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" scope. But this scope sends a very scary message to users on login: "This wil allow xxx to: see, edit or **delete all of your** Google Drive files" (bold is mine).

I don't want to *delete your files* and I don't want to edit *all of your files*: is there a way to reach my goal with a less scary scope?

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative to the `drive` scope, if you want to edit the files, is `drive.file`, which gives access to **files that you have opened or created with the app** ([ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)).

Since this is not an option for you, I'm afraid you'll have to use the *scary* scope.

#### Feature request:

Considering your situation, I think you might be interested in this Feature Request, regarding the possibility to restrict access to a specific folder. I think that could be very useful for you if it got implemented. I'd suggest you to star that issue, both to keep track of its development and to help prioritize its implemenation:

- [Drive Restrict access to folder when authorizing applications](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760598)

#### Related:

- [Google Drive API: 404 when accessing file someone else created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776810)
- [Google Sheet OAuth scopes to only access a few files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61886017)

Comment: Thank you. I can use drive.file but with drive.file I can't edit files shared with me: I can edit only file owned by me.

Comment: @MarcoCarnazzo Yes, that's why I mentioned you'll have to use the scary scope. Please consider accepting this, if it answered your question.