# Minimum Required Google Oauth Scope(s) to Read and Write specific (not all) Google Sheets Files?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Goodness, the OAuth landscape is elaborate! I've seen a bunch of posts that answer parts but not all of this question, including some that are old enough that there might be better answers now.

I'd like my app to be able to:

1. Read and write *exitsing* Google Sheet data using the [v4 Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values), not just when the user is present, but persistently
2. Gain access *only* those files the authorizing user grants permissions for (with a Picker), *NOT ALL* their Google Spreadsheets

My hope was to be able to use *just* the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope shown [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes).

After first getting metadata for a file, though, I'm getting 404 and 403 errors when I try to work with sheets not created by the app.

Before continuing to bang my head against the wall, I'm hoping to confirm that what I want to do is actually possible.

UPDATE:

I have since confirmed that we can do everything in 1 and 2 *except* address *existing* Google Sheets. I've only been able to selectively access sheets *created* on behalf of a user that has granted me the `drive.file` scope. (I have *not* confirmed that we *can't* come up with a way to edit existing files, and based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876633/google-sheet-oauth-scopes-to-only-access-a-few-files) that has a comment that mentions the `drive.install` scope, I still believe there's a way, so if you have one, please reply!

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no way to meet both of your requirements in the v4 sheets API. Google's OAuth solution is frustratingly limited, as you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks, IndevSmiles. What are the next best options in your opinion?

Comment: LOL, if I don't read this answer, it isn't true. Someone please offer an alternative to IndevSmiles; if there's agreement, what's the next best way that *tries* to adhere to least permissions principles?